# Inverting a large sparse R matrix with more than 2^31-1 nonzero elements

Tags: r, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, r-package

I am currently using `Matrix::solve()` to try and invert a 90000 x 90000 matrix. Memory is not a problem as I have access to a cluster. But the `Matrix::solve()` gives the error:

```
Error in .local(a, b = b, ...) :
  attempt to construct sparse matrix with more than 2^31-1 nonzero elements
```

Is there another R package that this will work with

Comment: Why are you trying to invert a matrix? General advice is to not do that.

Comment: trying to solve [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/632958/283493). I have tried iterative methods with sherman-morrison formula, but this is then very slow.

Comment: I think I am going to have to work out how the paper I refer to in the question I mentioned in my previous comment calculates it without inverting.

Comment: are you using the latest version of Matrix ?

Comment: I have just update from version 1.5.4 to 1.6.4, I will retry now, thanks.

Comment: See my comments on your linked answer. I think you're probably going to have to try to implement the Barone (1987) method for yourself, or ask somewhere else for a package that implements it ("is there a package/please find a package for me" is off-topic for both CV and SO, but there may be another forum where you could ask ... (ResearchGate?))

Answer (score 2):

The `p` slot of virtual classes `CsparseMatrix` and `RsparseMatrix` uses R's 32-bit integer type, which cannot represent positive integers greater than 2^31-1.

```r
> library(Matrix)
> getClassDef("CsparseMatrix")@slots[["p"]]
[1] "integer"
attr(,"package")
[1] "methods"
> identical(.Machine[["integer.max"]], as.integer(0x1p+31 - 1))
[1] TRUE
```

The last element of the `p` slot is the number of entries stored in the sparse matrix.  A corollary is that `CsparseMatrix` and `RsparseMatrix` cannot store more than 2^31-1 entries.

So, yes, you should avoid computing the inverse or at least avoid trying to represent the inverse using those classes if it requires more than 2^31-1 entries.  The situation can be expected to improve once R introduces a 64-bit integer type, but probably not before that.

In general, you should be solving `A * X = B` with

```r
> X <- solve(A, B)
```

which computes `inv(A) * B` without ever forming `inv(A)`.  If you are solving multiple systems involving `A`, then it is more efficient to do

```r
> library(Matrix)
> lu.A <- lu(A)
> X <- solve(lu.A, B)
```

reusing `lu.A` in subsequent calls to `solve`.

Comment: So if I wanted to invert a matrix `A` how would I do this in the method you described with `solve(. , .)`

Comment: `solve(A, B)` computes `inv(A) * B` without forming `inv(A)`.  The whole point is to _not_ invert `A`, i.e., to _not_ do something like `solve(A) %*% B` ...